# Stage Not Tracking MouseX or MouseY Without Clicking

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

I've a fairly simple little cs4 project where my desired effect is a clock face rotating in 3d space to match where the mouse is on the stage, but, for some reason, in order for the clock face to seek out the mouse position, I have to click the stage.  Is this happening for anyone else?  And, if so, why?

```
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;

var pp:PerspectiveProjection=new PerspectiveProjection();
pp.projectionCenter = new Point(225,250);
pp.fieldOfView = 55;
clock.transform.perspectiveProjection = pp;


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateClock);

function rotateClock(e:Event):void
{
    var xPcent:Number = mouseX/225;
    var yPcent:Number = mouseY/250;
    Tweener.addTween(clock, {rotationY:50 - (50*xPcent), rotationX:50 - (50*yPcent), time:2, transition:"easeOutCubic"});
}
```

Comment: hmm I ran your code (excluding the tween as I don't currently have the Tweener library) and it ran just fine, didn't need to click just moved the mouse and the MovieClip rotated in 3D space.

Comment: It runs fine when I test the file.. i.e. just export the .swf, but when I embed it in an html page, it seems to run finicky.

Comment: Is this happening on Mac? there is a bug related to this in some Mac browsers...

Comment: Oh, and using any other wmode than "window" might have this effect on some browsers also...

Comment: ah ok I was just running from the Flash IDE :)

Comment: @cay,  yes I was running FF on my mac.  do you have more info on that bug?

Comment: Adding tweens on each frame is a bit overkill (on MOUSE_MOVE doubly so), they're supposed to be added once and then run their course, just change the properties of the object directly instead.

Comment: @Grapefukt.. could you give an example?

Comment: @Grapefukt, I took the tweening out and ran a memory usage function, it seemed the same with or without the tweening.  I can't see getting the desired "smooth rotating" effect without essentially writing my own tween (using a distance percentage) so, how is it overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE event to the stage instead.